# What does Horizontal Mode do?

Tags: super-bomberman-r

When playing local multiplayer in *Super Bomberman R*, what does the “Horizontal Mode” option do?

[image: Horizontal Mode option]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Horizontal mode, in general, refers to holding a Nintendo Switch Joycon controller horizontally, with the analogue stick on the left and the buttons on the right, so that the controllers resemble conventional NES/SNES controllers. Contrasted with vertical mode, where the controllers are paired and played vertically.

With regards to Super Bomberman R, the option comes in handy when trying to play with 5 - 8 people, according to [Konami](https://www.konami.com/games/bomberman/r/us/en/page/controller_settings/):

> 6. Set the controllers to Horizontal Mode on the Character Selection screen of the Multiplayer Battle. This way all Joy-Con™ are set to horizontal and 8 players can join in the game.

Comment: This was probably done to get around the Switch's 4-controller limit. (Splitting 4 joycon pairs into 8 controllers)